# javascript time formatting/interpreting function?

Tags: javascript, time

I am working on a web-based application that will require users to enter a start and end time

I find selection boxes annoying for that purpose, and I am looking for any javascript functions that will interpret most entries that a user could put 
for example:

1p, 1pm, 1:00pm, 13, 13:00 would all be 1:00PM

I know I can write it, but if someone has already written a comprehensive one, it would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: @Anurag: why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: @JoeriSebrechts - good idea, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Date.JS](http://www.datejs.com/). The sample parser on their website correctly parses all the formats you have listed except `13`, which it considers to be the date and parses as `Dec 13` instead of `1PM`.

Comment: thanks...I checked it out, but it doesn't really suit my needs...a bit too robust

Comment: for anybody interested in using datejs for this purpose, this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012702/parse-only-a-time-string-with-datejs