# Comparing 2 Times with DateJS

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I've seen a few different questions on here regarding finding the difference between using two different dates.

My question is similar to [Parse ONLY a time string with DateJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012702/parse-only-a-time-string-with-datejs).

I basically have 2 time inputs:

`<input id="start_time" type="text">` 
`<input id="end_time" type="text">`

The format of these will always be: `07:15 AM` or `08:30 AM`

Essentially, what I am trying to do is ensure the `start_time` is not greater than the `end_time`.

I have tried using DateJS to parse the date, but it returns `null`:

```
Date.parseExact("03:15 PM", "HH:mm");    <--- returns null
```

How should I go about comparing the two input fields (using DateJS or something else) to ensure the start_time is not greater than the end_time?

Any help would be great.

Comment: The date string you're passing to `parseExact` doesn't match the format you're passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the AM/PM field to the format you're using to parse with. Try using

```
HH:mm tt
```

Instead of

```
HH:mm
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answering the question, but DateJS looks a bit outdated. I would suggest you take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/), where you can do this:

```
moment("03:15 PM", "hh:mm A").isAfter(moment("03:05 PM", "hh:mm A"));
// false
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This looks interesting, I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using toString?

```
var g = new Date("2012-01-11 03:15 PM");
console.log(g.toString('HH:mm'));
```

just add a ficticious date in order to obtain a valid date string format.
Since I guess you just need the Time not the date

It works fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parseExact` with the format revision presented by @matthewtole, or you should be able to just use 'Date.parse' as well.

`Date.parseExact` will provide better performance, but if you're just parsing two values, the performance improvement of `Date.parseExact` is probably not going to make much difference.

You can also use the `.isBefore()` function to check if one Date occurs before the other.

**Example**

```
var d1 = Date.parse("07:15 AM");
var d2 = Date.parse("08:30 AM");

d1.isBefore(d2); // true
```

Hope this helps