# Parse time data from HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a javascript widget on my page that outputs times for Sunrise and Sunset.  The following code is what gets output (assume that these times change every day).  I have **no control** over the output from the widget.

```
<div id="sun_container">
    <div class="details">
        Sunrise: <strong>7:00AM</strong> |
        Sunset: <strong>4:30PM</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Elsewhere on my page I have an image tag that looks like this:

```
<div id="sun_button">
    <img src="images/day.png">
</div>
```

I want to parse out the sunrise time and the sunset time and compare these against the current server time (which I can output via PHP if necessary).

If the current server time **is not** between the sunrise and sunset times, then I want to change the image `src` to `"images/night.png"`.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

**EDIT:** I'm now outputting the server time in the page `<head>` using:

`var server_time = "<?=date("H:i:s", time())?>";`

which outputs something like this:

`var server_time = "17:07:41";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it very easily with the [DateJS JavaScript library](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sunrise = Date.parse($(".details strong:eq(0)").text());
 var sunset = Date.parse($(".details strong:eq(1)").text());
    if(Date.parse("" + server_time).between(sunrise, sunset)) { 
       $("img").attr("src","images/day.png")
    }
    else {
       $("img").attr("src","images/night.png")
    }
});
</script>
```

[Try it here!](http://jsfiddle.net/tsabd/)

Comment: I don't really mind that I had to include an extra JS library. This answer includes everything I needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Once they're dates you can compare them easily using the built-in date properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this post: [What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javasc)

Same premise, it's javascript, but this seems to be the best solution.

**EDIT**
Also, see @Ender's solution on how to retrieve the data.

Comment: The post was helpful for parsing strings into dates, but didn't really help with the date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can get the sunrise/sunset times by doing something like the following:

```
var sunrise = $('#sun_container .details strong:eq(0)').text();
var sunset = $('#sun_container .details strong:eq(1)').text();
```

From there probably write the server time into a JS var, do your comparison, and then:

```
if (isNight) {
    $('#sun_button img').attr('src', 'images/night.png');
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: This was great for getting me started, but didn't include any info on parsing the strings sunrise and sunset into Dates and comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can generate a container like this with 24 hour time:

```
<div id="server_time">18:00</div>
<script>
$(function() {
// Assume server_time is 24hr
var server = new Date(Date.parse("2000-01-01 " + $('#server_time').text()));
var sunrise = $('#sun_container .details strong:eq(0)').first().text();
var sunset = $('#sun_container .details strong:eq(1)').last().text();

// strip off AM/PM
sunrise = sunrise.substring(0, sunrise.length-2);
sunset = sunset.substring(0, sunset.length-2);

// Parse to standard dates
sunrise = new Date(Date.parse("2000-01-01 " + sunrise)) ;
sunset = new Date(Date.parse("2000-01-01 " + sunset));
// Add tweleve hours to compensate for PM
sunset.setHours(sunset.getHours() + 12);

if (server < sunrise || server > sunset)
    $('#sun_button > img').attr('src', 'images/night');
});
</script>
```