# How to tell the difference between a time string and a non-time string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

**I need a function that can tell if a string is in a time format. Something along these lines:**

```
var string1 = "Normal String",
    string2 = "12:00pm";


function timeOrString(str) {
   if (str == A TIME) {
      alert('this is a time');
   }
   else {
      alert('this is a normal string');
   }
}

timeOrString(string1);
timeOrString(string2);
```

It could be something as simple as telling whether there is a number in the string?

Comment: You need to define your requirements better. What is "a time" here?

Comment: It's just a string that is in a time format

Comment: There are *lots* of "time formats" in this world.

Comment: You can have 12:00, 8:00:23, 08:00:23.678, 8:0:3pm ... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string1 = "Normal String",
    string2 = "12:00 pm";


function timeOrString(str){
  if(new Date("1/1/1900 " + str) != "Invalid Date" && str){
    alert("this is a valid time string");
  }else{
    alert("this is not a valid time string");
  }
}

timeOrString(string1);
timeOrString(string2);
```

That's one way of doing it.  It's messy but it'll work... most of the time. :P

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it... Some use Regular Expresions other value checks... Here are some examples:

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/val-time.html
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-date/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/timevalidation.aspx

But my recomendation, depending on what you are trying to do, its not use a text box to request the time, but use a jquery plugin to make date and time selectable, and control the input format that way:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof  and typeof operators

```
var theDay = new Date(1995, 11, 17); // Dec. 17, 1995
 if (theDay instanceof Date)
 {
  print("theDay is a Date object");
   // whatever else...
 }

var myString = new String();
var myDate = new Date();


    myString instanceof String; // returns true
    myString instanceof Object; // returns true
    myString instanceof Date;   // returns false
    myDate instanceof Date;     // returns true
    myDate instanceof Object;   // returns true
    myDate instanceof String;   // returns false
```

[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof)

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof)

Comment: But his input is always a string.

Comment: Why are you asking me? I'm not the OP. Anyway, the intention is very clear from the question (though the specific input string formats are not).

Comment: Convert you time to fake date

Comment: Huh? Can you use a full sentence please. And, again, it's not **my** time, but the OP's.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javasc   Convert time to javascript date

Comment: What ops mean   I'm not the OP.?

Comment: The OP is the Original Poster, i.e. _not me_.