# How to convert string to datetime using jquery?

Tags: asp.net

i just want to convert string to datetime and then store the date in asp.net calander control's Visible date property. Following is my code

```
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "dataCheck.aspx/calanderdates",
                 data: '{item:"' + item + '"}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",

                 success: function (response) {
                     var sdate = Date(response.d)

                       cal.attr("VisibleDate", sdate);

                 },
                 error: function () {
                     alert(msg.status);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

But code is not working

Comment: Try to know exactly where is the problem, use developer tools in Google chrome to detect if there is errors in the JavaScript code or in the response , the error may happen in the server side, detect your error position

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.Could you be more specific with your error as @Ahmed safan said?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729484/convert-a-time-string-say-1205-pm-into-a-datetime-using-date-parse-in-javascr might help

Comment: would you please show us what calanderdates() returns ?

Comment: There are better ways to do this: https://github.com/datejs/Datejs will fulfill your requirement.
Also, can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712246/format-date-time-in-jquery link to create your own.

Answer (score -1):

```
var sdate = Date.parse(response.d);
```

Comment: Hi Naoe, Thanks for reply. I try this line but it dosn't work. It return 1276885800000 value