# Flatpickr populate div text with chosen date

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

My `.auto-input` function populates the container div `.text` when you type in an `input`, but it won't take the value in the `flatpickr input` field and populate the `.flatpickr` div text when you choose a date.

How do I get the text inside of `.flatpickr` to populate based on the input from `#flapickr`?

```js
$('.auto-input').keyup(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').html($this.val());
});
var example = flatpickr("#flatpickr", {
  locale: "en",
  altInput: true,
  dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
  minDate: "1950-01-01",
  allowInput: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="auto-input" id="text" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="auto-input" id="flatpickr" type="text" placeholder="deal expires on...">
</div>
<div class="input-fill-holder">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="flatpickr">Fill Date Here</div>
</div>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/themes/airbnb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/l10n/fr.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `onChange` or `onClose` event hook and then update the `.flatpickr` **div** accordingly. Read more here: https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#hooks

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yhn4peey/4/

Here is the example:

```js
$('.auto-input').keyup(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').html($this.val());
});
var example = flatpickr("#flatpickr", {
  locale: "en",
  altInput: true,
  dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
  minDate: "1950-01-01",
  allowInput: false,
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        $(".flatpickr").html(dateStr);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="auto-input" id="text" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="auto-input" id="flatpickr" type="text" placeholder="deal expires on...">
</div>
<div class="input-fill-holder">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="flatpickr">Fill Date Here</div>
</div>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/themes/airbnb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/l10n/fr.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea how to format the container text to match what's in the Flatpickr input (Jan 1, 2018)?

Comment: Seriously, read the documentation, haha :D https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/#escaping-formatting-tokens It's all there. Just replace `dateFormat: "d-m-Y"` with format you need in the config.

Comment: I checked out the docs but couldn't find anything about formatting the onChange date.

Comment: I just wrote that you need to change `dateFormat: "d-m-Y"` in the config with the formatting you need. Another alternative (which won't make sense in using as the flatpickr provides the date formating already) is [this solution found in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712246/format-date-time-in-jquery). I suggest sticking with the builtin configuration options.

Comment: Oh I see now. The `dateFormat: "d-m-Y"` I had in the function wasn't changing the input from the picker input like I thought, but it actually was changing the onChange text. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem @KyleUnderhill Have a great day!