# How to change dynamically the value of a label in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, label

I'm developing a project in MVC 3 (CRUD)... I want to create a reservation for a tennis court...

**Page:**

[image]

So, when I type a "Start time" ("heure de début" in French) I want to increase the "FinishTime" **in red** ("heure de fin" in French) dynamically... If it's a simple match increase by 1:00 and if not by 2:00...

I'm beginner in MvC3 so I have no idea how to do that... Of course, I'm not request that you make my work but the right method to do that and if it's possible an example...

*View:*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Reservation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Simple)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Simple)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Simple)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-fieldFinishTime">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FinishTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishTime)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Terrain N°")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.TennisCourtID,ViewBag.TennisCourtID as SelectList)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I've forget to precise that all clubs can have different schedule... **For example:**

***Club 1:*** 
Simple: 1:00
Double: 2:00

***Club2:***
Simple: 1:30
Double: 2:30

So in my database's table TennisClub I have an attribute SimpleGameTime and DoubleGameTime... Sorry :(

Comment: If you want to do that dynamically, ie. without POSTing the form, the only solution is Javascript. I'm not entirely sure how the value would be handled in the script, a string? Anyway, using jQuery you could do it like that: `$(document).ready( function() { $("#StartTime").keyup(function() { var value = $(this).val(); });});` , then possibly increase this value and set as the FinishTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the `change` event of the `Input` for Start time (check its ID in rendered HTML):

```
$("input#TheId").bind("onchange", onStartTimeChanged);
```

Define a function to parse a time, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas) here on SO.

In the `onStartTimeChanged` function get the check box state (update with correct jQuery selector for the control):

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
```

Then simply add the parsed date with the proper offset and write that back to the End Time control using `toLocaleTimeString()`.

**Note:** I assumed you'll use JavaScript to perform calculations on client-side. If you prefer to do everything on server-side you have to add an AJAX-enabled method in your controller with the start time and the flag as parameters. In your `onStartTimeChanged` function you have to call it and asynchronously update the end time when the function return. If there's a lot of logic (or it's not trivial) I prefer the server-side solution with AJAX.

For example (I didn't check the code so use it cum grano salis) to call a server-side method with POST (you have to pass parameters, as alternative you may use getJson with GET only but you have to work with routing):

```
function ComputeEndTime(matchStartTime, isSimpleMatch) {
   var url = '<%= Url.Action("ControllerName", "ComputeEndTime") %>';
   $.post(url, { startTime: matchStartTime, isSimple: isSimpleMatch },
      function(data) {
         return data.endTime;
      }
   );
}
```

And your server side function:

```
[AcceptPost]
public ActionResult ComputeEndTime(string startTime, bool isSimple)
{
   // Perform your calculations then convert to string
   string calculatedEndTime = "";

   return Json(new { endTime = calculatedEndTime });
}
```

Comment: I've forget to precise that all clubs can have different schedule... For example:

Club 1: Simple: 1:00
        Double: 2:00

Club2: Simple: 1:30
       Double: 2:30

So in my database's table TennisClub I have an attribute SimpleGameTime and DoubleGameTime... Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will check that

Comment: Updated with a small example for server-side processing.