# Sort time array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to sort an array of form
["01:00 am","06:00 pm" ,"12:00 pm","03:00 am","12:00 am"]

Please suggest.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var times = ['01:00 am', '06:00 pm', '12:00 pm', '03:00 am', '12:00 am'];

times.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b);
});

console.log(times);
```

Comment: Note that in 2017, this is actually a bad idea, as calling the Date constructor with a string that's anything other than an ISO 8601-formatted date will not work cross-browser. Better to use the solutions outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/q/141348/215552.

Answer (score 0):

How about taking a look at Underscore.js SortBy?
http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy