# Parse Date in Chrome (with time)

Tags: javascript, datetime

The following code seems to work in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```
var d = Date.parse("Sep 23, 2012 24:0:0");
alert (d);
```

It alerts the milliseconds in Firefox but I get a NaN in Chrome.

Of course, the last 3 numbers (24:0:0) might not be counted as a 'date', but I'd like to have a simple solution to this to make the code work cross-browser.

Comment: Note: Chrome just has an issue with invalid times -- `alert(Date.parse("Sep 23, 2012 23:0:0"))` works fine. You might be better off parsing & using the Date Constructor yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the format you listed:

```
var parts = "Sep 23, 2012 21:1:2".match(/(.*) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/)
var d = new Date(parts[1])
d.setHours(parts[2])
d.setMinutes(parts[3])
var tstamp = d.setSeconds(parts[4])
```

Not sure if you ultimately want a Date object or integer timestamp, but this should get you both.

Comment: thanks a lot! Worked like a charm! Needed it to get a countdown to work

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't seem to support time...

try `Date.parse("Sep 23, 2012");`
it should work

Date.parse is not supposed to parse time according to specs.
You need third party code.
See :
[What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas)

Comment: wow thats obvious. I'm asking for an alternative that works for both