# Subtracting two times in AM/PM format using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datejs

I'm using a `date.js` plugin to convert my times into date object and then I'm subtracting them.But the result is not valid. My time is in this format `11:00 pm` 
This is what I'm doing:

```
var tim_i = $('#in_time').val();
var tim_o = $('#out_time').val();
total_tim = "";
if (tim_i && tim_o ){
    d1 = Date.parse(tim_i);
    d2 = Date.parse(tim_o);
    date_diff = new Date(d2 - d1);
    total_tim=date_diff.getHours() + ':' + date_diff.getMinutes();
}

$('#total_time').val(total_tim);
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas It explains how to parse times with JS.

Comment: Be aware that [Datejs is abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Answer (score 1):

The TimeSpan class in Datejs might help simplify the problem.

Here's a sample you can run in Firebug that parse the two strings into Date objects, then output the difference in Hours + Minutes.

**Example**

```
var d1 = Date.parse("6:30 am");
var d2 = Date.parse("11:00 pm");

var diff = new TimeSpan(d2 - d1);

console.log("Hours: ", diff.hours);
console.log("Minutes: ", diff.minutes);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: You could even simplify into one line if you really want to be terse.

```
new TimeSpan(Date.parse("11:00 pm")-Date.parse("6:30 am")).toString("H:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tim_i = new Date($('#in_time').val());
var tim_o = new Date($('#out_time').val());
total_tim = "";
if (tim_i && tim_o) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(tim_o.getTime() - tim_i.getTime());
    var getHours = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600));
    var getMinutes = Math.ceil(timeDiff % (1000 * 60));
    total_tim = getHours + ':' + getMinutes;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this as the result: NaN:NaN