# how to convert "9:00PM" string to datetime in script

Tags: javascript, datetime

I get invalid date while converting this string to datetime in javascript. Please help,

```
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var a="9:00 PM";
var f= new Date(a.toString());
alert(f);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel you might want to take a look at http://momentjs.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cc69S/

Comment: The problem is that `9:00 PM` is not a date.   It's a time only.   If you try your code again and set `var a="01/17/2014 9:00 PM";` you will see your code works on valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `9:00 PM` is not a date. It's a time only. If you try your code again and set var `a="01/17/2014 9:00 PM"`; you will see your code works on valid dates.

That said, if you want today's date, plus the timestamp, you can use this code:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var a="9:00 PM";
  var f= new Date();
  var now = new Date();

  f = (now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + a;

  alert(f);
}
```

This gets today's date, and appends your timestamp to the end.

[**CODEPEN DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bFzmn)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(hm){    
    return new Date().toDateString()+ hm;   
}

var a= " 9:00 PM";
alert(myFunction(a))
```

/*  returned value: (String) Fri Jan 17 2014 9:00 PM */