# How to sort data hourwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects of this type

```
Obj = { timeEnd:"06:45 AM",
        timeStart:"04:23 AM"
      }
```

Array is of type **[obj1,obj2, ....]** of particular day.

This array defines that how much time is spend on activities.

I want to recreate or transform this array into time wise array like

```
obj = { '4-5 AM' : 37,
        '5-6 AM' : 60,
        '6-7 AM' : 45
      }
```

I have tried to search could not help. I am a noob.

Please let me know if you need any other info. Ultimate goal is to create a hourwise chart.js graph

Comment: which time is grouped? what is the number behind?

Comment: Diffrence between timeStart and timeEnd can be in minutes or hours. I have to saprate it hourwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the 24 h values and count until the target hour is reached and then get the rest of the minutes to add.

```js
function getHourParts(object) {

    function getKey(h) {
       return h + '-' + (h + 1);
    }

    function getTime(s) {
        var t = s.split(':').map(Number);
        return { h: t[0], m: t[1] };
    }

    var result = {},
        start = getTime(object.timeStart),
        end = getTime(object.timeEnd);

    while (start.h < end.h) {
        result[getKey(start.h)] = 60 - start.m;
        ++start.h;
        start.m = 0;
    }
    result[getKey(end.h)] = end.m - start.m;
    return result;
}

console.log(getHourParts({ timeStart: '04:23', timeEnd: '06:45' }));
console.log(getHourParts({ timeStart: '12:03', timeEnd: '12:05' }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of how the problem could be resolved.
Consider use of `Map` object makes the benefit of `Object` distinction (not needed if there is no time overlap) and `Array` length.

```js
var durations = [{timeStart: "04:23 AM", timeEnd: "06:45 AM", }, {timeStart: "09:23 AM", timeEnd: "11:30 AM", }, {timeStart: "11:09 PM", timeEnd: "01:19 PM", }];

function getValue(time) {
 var [hour, minute, period] = time.replace(':', ' ').split(' ');
 var date = new Date();
 date.setHours((period === 'PM' ? 12 : 0) + +hour, +minute);
 return date;
}

var result = {};

durations.forEach(duration => {
 var time = getValue(duration.timeStart),
  end = getValue(duration.timeEnd);

 for (var hour = time.getHours(); hour <= end.getHours(); hour++) {
  var endMinute = hour === end.getHours() ? end.getMinutes() : 59,
   minute = 0,
   hourSpan = `${hour}-${hour + 1}`;

  result[hourSpan] = result[hourSpan] || new Map;
  while (minute <= endMinute)
   result[hourSpan].set(minute, minute++);
 }
});
Object.keys(result).forEach(span => {
 result[span] = result[span].size;
});
console.clear();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by parsing the time from your input string into a date object and then comparing the date objects:

Working Demo here: http://live.datatables.net/erefom/2/edit#preview

Source here: http://live.datatables.net/erefom/2/edit

Also see this answer: [What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas#141504)?

Comment: interesting, I will take a look over this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sort any array with respect to time is using the UTC Timestamp value. 
First convert the stringValue into timestamp and then sort the array according to timestamp values.

Comment: How to divide them based on hours ?

Comment: I think you can subtract the timestamps to get the actual difference in seconds.

Comment: and you can convert it into hours

Comment: Basically it may sound complicated but its really easy.

Comment: but difference has no am/pm.

Comment: to avoid the issue of am/pm I suggested you to use timestamp. It takes care of everything, even the day.

Comment: I have already realized that and converted the dates into 24 hours format. And yes I have got the diffrence in terms of interval but I don't get how the interval can be distributed hourwise. For example if some thing was done in between 12:45 - 13:21. So what I want to do is to save the diffrence in respective 1 hour duration. Like '12-13' will have 15 minutes and '13-14' will have 21. You got me ?  @Nina Scholz