# Add time to string of hh:mm:ss javasctipt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have the following string returned by my web service: '10:00:00'.

It is successfully being disabled in my timepicker via:

```
$('#appointmentTimeTextbox').timepicker('option',
                                        'disableTimeRanges',
                                        [[obj.appointmentTime, obj.appointmentEndTime]]);
```

What I would like is to add 30 minutes (one option in the timepicker) to `obj.appointmentEndTime`. I have tried:

```
var appointmentEndTime = new date(obj.appointmentEndTime);
    appointmentEndTime.setHours(appointmentEndTime.getHours() + .5);
```

to no avail.

Comment: .5 should be 5 (without the dot)

Comment: @ymz . . . definitely not . . . that would add 5 hours.

Comment: then why not using 30 with setMinutes() and getMinutes()?

Comment: I believe the problem is in the conversion to date: var appointmentEndTime = new date(obj.appointmentEndTime);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues going on here:

1) This may just be a typo in the question, but the date constructor must be capitalized: `new Date(...`

2) The `setHours()` method only takes integer values for the "hours" parameter . . . from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

> **hoursValue**
>
> integer between 0 and 23, representing the hour.

You can add in a half an hour two ways: by providing a "minutes" parameter in the `setHours()` call:

```
appointmentEndTime.setHours(appointmentEndTime.getHours(), 30);
```

. . . or by simply using the `setMinutes()` method:

```
appointmentEndTime.setMinutes(appointmentEndTime.getMinutes() + 30);
```

3) When you create the new date value with:

```
var appointmentEndTime = new date(obj.appointmentEndTime);
```

. . . you are working with a brand new `Date` object, so you will either need to copy the new time value back into the original `obj.appointmentEndTime` property, or you will need to create the value from the new `appointmentEndTime` variable, and pass that into the `timepicker()` method instead of `obj.appointmentEndTime`.

---

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I looked at your Fiddle and the issue that you are having now is that you can't create a date with simply a time value:

```
var appoinementEndTime = new Date('10:00:00');
```

Again, looking to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (a **great** resource, by the way), the valid inputs for the `Date` constructor are:

```
new Date();           // The exact moment at the creation of the Date
new Date(value);      // In milliseconds, since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC
new Date(dateString); // A string value representing a date (see link for valid formats)
new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

So your best option would be to pick a date (the current date would be easiest), and then override the time values on that date, to get the value that you want:

```
var endTimeArray = obj.appoinementEndTime.split(":");
var appoinementEndTime = new Date();
appoinementEndTime.setHours(endTimeArray[0],      // the hours value
                            endTimeArray[1] + 30, // the minutes value
                            endTimeArray[2],      // the seconds value
                            0);                   // the milliseconds value
```

Using that (and your value of '10:00:00`), the time value of the date should be`10:30:00`(which you can create using the`getHours()`,`getMinutes()`, and`getSeconds`methods on`appoinementEndTime`).

Comment: It was a typo with Date. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgkyoywq/9/ I am getting an Invalid Date

Comment: Great work! The only thing I had to do is add a '0' to the end of seconds because for some reason it's a single digit. The MDN is a fantastic resource that I do not use nearly enough. Thank you so much for your help talemyn

Comment: Oh, and on a side note, the `setHours()` method worked well with your value of "10", because it was less than 12, but you **will** have to make sure that the "hours" parameter is in 24-format, in order to set it correctly for all times (with midnight equaling "0")