# Extract time range

Tags: javascript, regex

Need some help with regex for extracting time from the following string:

> 3:00 am - 4:00 pm Transform data blah blah blah

or

> 3:00 am Transform data blah blah blah

Following regex works for the first format but it does not work for the second format: `/\d{1,2}:\d\d\s([AaPp][Mm])?\s?-?\s\d{1,2}:\d\d\s([AaPp][Mm])/g`

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: this is what you want:-https://eval.in/817294?

Comment: Enclose second section in an optional cluster `\d{1,2}:\d\d\s([AaPp][Mm])?\s?(-?\s\d{1,2}:\d\d\s([AaPp][Mm]))?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Maybe this approach would interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/141504/1575353

Comment: Hey Revo, it only filters start date but not end date

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modifier `g` allows finding all occurrences. Thus you can simplify your expression. Also the modifier `i` allows case insensitive matching.

```
/\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s(am|pm)/gi
```

This is how to use :

```
var str = '3:00 am - 4:00 pm Transform data blah blah blah', 
times = str.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s(am|pm)/gi);
console.log(times);
```

`times` will be an array that contains the matches.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is not okay with this answer?

Comment: Hey Lorenz, thanks for your help. It only filters start date

Comment: @indu527 I'm astonished. When I execute above code, `console.log` will output both dates. Reconsider your vote.

Comment: Never mind it works great! sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I did not down vote. Someone else did. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem, never mind!