# invalid date format TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, datetime

I am passing in time values `departureTime` such as '12:00' here. Then I try to convert it into a date and perform a subtraction. However, the result of timeOfDeparture and then time till departure is invalid. How can I fix this and make everything in a uniform type?

```
    const timeNow = new Date();
    console.log('TIME NOW', timeNow)
    const timeOfDeparture = new Date(departureTime);
    console.log('TIME of Departure', timeOfDeparture)
    const timeTillDeparture = Math.floor((timeOfDeparture.valueOf() - timeNow.valueOf()) / 60000);
    console.log('TIME TILL DEP', timeOfDeparture)
```

Example console logs:

```
TIME NOW Tue Oct 06 2020 15:47:35 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
TIME of Departure Invalid Date
TripTimes.tsx:17 TIME TILL DEP NaN
```

Comment: date string must be full date, not just hour. For example `const timeOfDeparture = new Date('October 6, 2020 12:00:00');`

Comment: where is the `departureTime` ? Is it undefined?

Comment: Is it possible to get current date and add 1 hour to it? That would fix my problem of defining a future time value for now. @firatozcevahir

Comment: yes it is. `const myDate = new Date(); myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() +1);` this will add 1 hour to current date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a time into a Date object from user input in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/how-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javascript)

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date object doesn't take hours as an argument. you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

> There are four ways of instantiating a date:

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

If your app relies on date manipulation, or if you want to manipulate dates more easily, consider using helper libraries like [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/).

For example, if your departure time is on the same date but just on a different hour, your departure time using **momentJs** will be

```
moment().hour(departureHour).minute(departureMinute);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get current date and add 1 hour to it? That would fix my problem of defining a future time value for now.

Comment: Yes, you can try `date.setHours()`. More about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp)

Comment: No, sorry. `setHours()` will just set the hour to a defined value. If you want to add 1 hour to the current date you do `new Date(d.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000))`. where you simply add 1 hour (in milliseconds) to the current date

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a Javascript Date object you cannot pass only hours and minutes. You can use the empty constructor or data constructor

```
new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)
```

but the first two arguments (year and month) are obligatory at least. You could get data from *timeNow* and add the time values from *departureTime*. Example:

```
const timeNow = new Date();
console.log('TIME NOW', timeNow)
let departureTimeArray = departureTime.split(":");
console.log('Hour of Departure', departureTimeArray[0]);
console.log('Minutes of Departure', departureTimeArray[1]);
const timeOfDeparture = new Date(timeNow.getFullYear(), timeNow.getMonth(), timeNow.getDate(), departureTimeArray[0], departureTimeArray[1]);
console.log('TIME of Departure', timeOfDeparture);
const timeTillDeparture = Math.floor((timeOfDeparture.valueOf() - timeNow.valueOf()) / 60000);
console.log('TIME TILL DEP', timeOfDeparture)
```

I hope this solution helps you.